# Php sort multi dimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

[php: alphabetically sort multi-dimensional array by its key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645990/php-alphabetically-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-its-key)

I'm trying to do the exact same thing as the guy in the thread above me. But my ksort($array) seems to return a number 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to provide some sample code if you want people to help you :-). How did you use ksort? What does your array look like?

Comment: Can you show us the array you're attempting to sort?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php is a good starting point; or post code.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/function.ksort.php):

> **bool** ksort ( array **&**$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

You see, ksort returns a boolean value, and directly works on the given array (note the reference sign`&`). So what you're probably doing is assigning the return value of `ksort`, like:

```
$array = ksort($array);
```

instead of, just:

```
ksort($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function does in-place sorting, the function return TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Refer to example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

**The sorted result is in the variable $fruits, not from the function's return value.**

If you try print_r($fruits), you will get the result like this

```
Array
(
    [a] => orange
    [b] => banana
    [c] => apple
    [d] => lemon
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ksort()` doesn't return an array, it manipulates the array you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't literally return an 1, it returns true:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.